# HTML form validation with the “pattern” attribute

Tags: html, regex, forms, validation

I am trying to come up with a valid pattern for an HTML form. I would like to allow `*@student.*.edu.vn`

This is my code:

```
 <input 
       type="text" 
       name="mail"  
       pattern="([a-z]|[0-9])+(@{1})+(student)+(.)+[a-z]+(.edu.vn)"
   />
```

It does not work as I would like. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does "doesn't work as I would like" mean? Is it allowing more than what you want? Is it not allowing what you want? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern (regular expression) is slightly wrong as you haven't escaped all your special characters such as the `.` and have some unnecessary parts within it. Try using the following slightly modified pattern instead:

`([a-z]|[0-9])+@student\.[a-z]+\.edu\.vn`

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="mail" pattern="([a-z]|[0-9])+@student\.[a-z]+\.edu\.vn" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Note:** Make sure that you also do validation on the server-side as anyone entering values into a form can remove the `pattern` to bypass this check.

Comment: I'm sorry. It does not work as I would like. What I am doing wrong?`if ( ! (preg_match('([a-z]|[0-9])+@student\.[a-z]+\.edu\.vn)', $billing_email )) )`

Comment: @LêNghĩa Try  `if (!(preg_match('/([a-z]|[0-9])+@student\.[a-z]+\.edu\.vn/', $billing_email ))) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution which is slightly more easy to read and is less strict (which is a good thing because e-mail addresses can contain a lot more characters than just lowercase alpha-numeric ones. Don't forget to do proper validation on the backend using an e-mail validator.

```
<form>
  <input 
   type="text" 
   name="mail"  
   pattern=".+@student\..+\.edu.vn"
 />
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```